# Java -> Context, Expression expected?

Tags: java, android, android-context

I'm trying to learn and make an Android app via Java and Android Studio. My extent of Java is a few hours of youtube studying and a basic college course two years ago. I do know how to code however. I'm proficient with Python.

I wish to use this bluetooth library (https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary) so that I can communicate simply between a phone and a bluetooth enabled ESP32 microcontroller.

In my project I created a button which I'll use for testing this library.

```
*snip*
        //my button
        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.myBtn); //use R.id for the button id
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //button listener
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //add whatever code here
                Log.e("my app", "log msg test"); //outputs to logcat window
                BluetoothSPP bt = new BluetoothSPP(Context);

                if(!bt.isBluetoothAvailable()) {
                    Log.e("my app", "bluetooth is not available");
                } else {
                    Log.e("my app", "bluetooth is available");
                }

            }
*snip*
```

I'm stuck on:

```
BluetoothSPP bt = new BluetoothSPP(Context);
```

Context gives me an error saying expression expected. I looked up what Context is in Java and understand why that would be a thing. However, I have no idea how to implement it, let alone, the proper context here.

Comment: You need to post *exact error messages*. "Context" is almost certainly not giving you an error, but the compiler, indicating that "Context" is the closest item it can point you to. (The immediate problem is that `Context` is the name of a class, and you should be providing either a variable or the result of a method call.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your code is in a class that is inherited from Activity class

i.e. class MainActivity extends Activity

you can try passing like this:

```
BluetoothSPP bt = new BluetoothSPP(MainActivity.this);
```

(because Activity is implementing context)

if it is inside something like a View class or a fragment you should try something like this:

```
BluetoothSPP bt = new BluetoothSPP(getContext());
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the context for me a bit. getApplicationContext() also worked.

Answer (score 1):

If it is for activity

```
BluetoothSPP bt = new BluetoothSPP(MainActivity.this);
or
BluetoothSPP bt = new BluetoothSPP(this);
or
BluetoothSPP bt = new BluetoothSPP(getApplicationContext());
```

If it for fragment

```
BluetoothSPP bt = new BluetoothSPP(getActivty());
```